# Should I set cell.bound / cell.frame in cellForItemAtIndexPath?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uicollectionview

Should I set `cell.bound` / `cell.frame` in `UITableView`'s datasource method?

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UICollectionViewCell! {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CompoundStatementCollectionViewCell

    cell.bounds = ..
```

or implementing `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` indicates the needed cell size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not set bounds/frame in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`: the right place to set up the size of the cell is `sizeForItemAtIndexPath`, you can also use it with `insetForSectionAtIndex` if you want to set up spacing between cell, header and footer.

Comment: my `UICollectionViewCell` "moves out" when rotating, shouldn't I set `frame.origin.x` coordinate in `layoutSubviews`?

Comment: @János, No you shouldn't touch cell's frame directly. If the collection view needs to look differently in portrait and landscape orientation you can set up different sizes/insets base on orientation, something like that (if orientation == portrait {..} else {...} in insetForSectionAtIndex/sizeForItemAtIndexPath.